# How do I make it so that using CustomTkinter I can accept an input by pressing 'Enter'?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, customtkinter

I was able so successfully place the input module earlier but now when I try to implement code to use 'Enter' to accept the input I'm not even able to get it to pack. If anyone can help me it would be thoroughly appreciated. Eventually I am trying to make it so that whatever typed ends up being incrementally placed as a title in a column centered to the left of the entry widget but I will work on that later. (this is the UI for a text adventure game)

Below is the code I have so far

```
#imports
import time, os, sys, logging
from pynput import *
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import simpledialog
import tkinter
import time
import tkinter as tk

userin = ''

#graphics
the_path_text = '''
┏┓┏┓╋╋╋╋╋╋╋╋┏┓┏┓
   ┃┗┫┗┳━┓┏━┳━┓┃┗┫┗┓
   ┃┏┫┃┃┻┫┃╋┃╋┗┫┏┫┃┃
   ┗━┻┻┻━┛┃┏┻━━┻━┻┻┛
   ╋╋╋╋╋╋╋┗┛'''

#window
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("800x520")
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
root.title('The Path')   

photo = PhotoImage(file = "D:\\pathpic.png")
root.iconphoto(False, photo)

myfont = ("Roboto Mono",30)

frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master = root)
frame.pack(pady = 20, padx = 60, fill = 'both', expand = True)

#splash/start screen

#loading
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root, text="Loading", font= ('Roboto', 20))
label.pack()

# Incrementally add dots
for i in range(3):
    label.configure(text="Loading" + "." * (i + 1))
    time.sleep(.5)
    root.update()

# Clear the label text
label.configure(text="")

# Incrementally add dots again
for i in range(3):
    label.configure(text="Loading" + "." * (i + 1))
    time.sleep(.5)
    root.update()

label.configure(text="  ")

#splash logo
label_path_logo = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text= the_path_text, font = ('Roboto', 20))
label_path_logo.pack(pady =12, padx = 10)

#clearing splash/ main game loop
start = 0
def clear_start():
    time.sleep(.2)
    global frame, root
    frame.destroy()
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    start_button.destroy()
    start = 1

#main game    
start_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, text="Enter the path", command = clear_start)
start_button.pack(padx = 6, pady=20)
while start == 1:
    #main text console
    main_entry = root.entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root, textvariable=userin, placeholder_text="Enter Command")
    main_entry.pack(side = BOTTOM,fill = BOTH, pady = 5, padx = 200 )


def process(event=None):
    content = main_entry.get() # get the contents of the entry widget
    print(content) # for example
    main_entry.bind('<Return>', process)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're calling `.bind()` on the Entry from within the function that would be called by the bind being triggered - in other words, it can never be called in the first place.  The usual place for `.bind()` is right after the creation of the widget.  (And you need to get rid of that `while start == 1:` loop - you're trying to create an infinite number of Entries.

Comment: The while loop is useless becaue `start` is 0 when the while loop is executed, so the code inside the while loop will never be executed.